# Unable to inform the ScoreDirector of a planning entity update during a problemfactchange in Bavet

Tags: optaplanner

When trying to inform the ScoreDirector of changes to a planning entity in Bavet, I consistently get the error:

The tuple (From *[class name]* with 0 children) already has a dirty state (CREATING) so it cannot transition to newState (UPDATING).

The instance is retrieved using scoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObjectOrReturnNull() and trying to change it with scoreDirector.(before/after)ProblemPropertyChanged(entity) as well as deleting and recreating it both result in this error. However, the entity should definitely be initialized at this point because these updates are attempted well after the planner has started returning valid solutions. I have not been able to find examples of anyone else running into this issue, I suspect because Bavet is not in widespread usage, so any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bavet is experimental technology at this point (CS-D is the default). Looks like a bug in Bavet. Might you have a reproducer? Ideally, we can isolate that reproducer as a unit test in `UniConstraintStreamTest` or `BiConstraintStreamTest` to fix it.